# Blender closes when I select animate or render

Tags: radeon-prorender-render-engine

Fresh install of 3.6 in school lab running WIN10 that closes/crashes Blender when you select animate or render. This even happens on a blank project. Video card is Radeon RX640, drivers updated, new Dell desktop Optiplex 3000. Any recommendations? Thanks.

Comment: we are no Blender developers here. I recommend using Help -> report a bug in Blender so that the developers can fix that.

Comment: Hey there! Is it crashing on a default startup file or you load a specific project? In the first case - it sounds like a bug. If you load a project file, please test it on a previous version of Blender. If it works there - report it as a bug. If it still crashes - then your file may be broken. Sharing your blend file can help confirming the crash on other machines.